# Variance of $2$-d random points projected onto a line

Tags: probability-distributions, vectors, normal-distribution

Assume that we take normally distributed random points in $\mathbb{R}^2$, which follow $\mathcal{N}(\mu, \sigma^2)$, where $\mu = (1,1)^T$ and $\sigma^2 = 0.4$.

Now suppose that we project these points to the line $y = x$ and thus each point $(a,b)$ gets mapped to $\left(\frac{a+b}{2}, \frac{a+b}{2}\right)$.

Seeing the initial $2$-d points as $1$-d points onto $y=x$, the new mean would be:

$$
\tilde{\mu} = 1
$$

**My question is**: what would be the new variance $\tilde{\sigma}$ for the projections?

Comment: You can find a formula for the linear combination of normal random variables.

Comment: @student how can I express the projection as a linear combination of normal random variables?

Comment: A projection is a linear operation! The iid random variables $x, y$ get mapped to $z = (x+y)/2$ and you can find the distribution of $z$ from that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The projection of any d-dimensional normal distribution with d*s^2 variance onto a line has s^2 variance!

The probability density function of a d-dimensional normal distribution centered at 0 with d*s^2 variance is just the product of d normal probability distribution functions of s^2 variance.

If we project that onto a single dimension, and integrate with respect to each other dimension over -inf to inf, we see the terms go to 1, and we're left with our singular dimensional normal distribution function multiplied by our delta squared term.

I am rushed, I can add math later, hopefully this can help you now.